# Better UML class diagram structure to represent marriage of individuals

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Currently I am working on a part of a bigger project, but I am not quite sure how to approach this part of the system.

[image: UML class diagram made in PowerDesigner]

Each individual can be married multiple times, each marriage needs to have an officiant, partner1, partner2 and witnesses. Individuals can represent these roles in multiple marriages.

I am wondering if there is a way to represent all of the necessary individuals with less associations, since the diagram quickly turns into a mess when looking at the whole system.

[Updated class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6suGP.png)

Comment: You are missing a "d" in Indivi**d**ual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace *partner1* and *partner2* by *partner* with multiplicity 2, and of course same for *partnerWitness*

*individualId* and *marriageId* are wrong because written underlined that mean they are *static*. Probably they are primary-key, but they are instance-member, not class-member. You can also name them *id*, useless to have a prefix

What is *statusPartner* ? is that can be supported by a class-association ?

The separated relation Individual -> Marriage is wrong because like that it can be for a marriage which not the same as the marriage the individual participate whatever its role, and this is not what you want. So remove it and use bidirectional relations

From your remark

> statusPartner is simply status of the partner before marriage (divorced, widow and so on)

that enforce to manage it through a class-association :

- With only *partner* you cannot know  for who is *statusPartner1* and *statusPartner2*, of course you do not have that problem in case of a class-association.
- You can also move that attribute in Individual but in that case it exist not only for the partner and that has no lot of sense to have it

So for instance :

[image]

Note it is also possible to use only one relation for both the officiant and witness using a class-association :

[image]

with a constraint saying there are two Individuals with the role *witness* and one with the role *officiant*

The role can also be an enumeration or replaced by the `isWitness` being a boolean etc.

It is also possible to use only one class-association :

[image]

with a first constraint saying the role of a *Partner* is *partner* and a second saying at a marriage there are two Individuals with the role *witness* and one with the role *officiant* and two with the role *partner*

Comment: @bruno statusPartner is simply status of the partner before marriage (divorced, widow and so on). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @bunnytechnician that enforce the class-association, I edited my answer, please reread it

Comment: I added an updated image above, I hope that is what you had in mind. Again, thank you for your advice!

Comment: @bunnytechnician no, I edited my answer to put a first diagram corresponding to the first version of my answer, and 2 others for two other ways to do

Comment: The next step is to make `Mariage` a specialization of `Contract`, enlarge the enumeration of roles to add parties,  generalise the associations with individuals by settling it at level of the contract,  and leave the specific contraints to the mariage ;-)

Comment: @bruno Your specialization of an association class is very inspiring,  and lead me to asks this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62973692/3723423 for UML language-lawyers ;-)

Comment: @Christophe yes there are lot of ways to model. It is probably the first time I specialize a class-association. I answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62973692/3723423

Answer (score 0):

1. Perfectly! But notice that in the beginning there were partner1Witness and partner2Witness, that is, each partner has his own witness.
2. first constraint saying the role of a Partner is partner and a second saying at a marriage there are two Individuals with the role witness and one with the role officiant and two with the role partner
   may be diagramming

Possible scheme in the picture
[image]

Comment: The OP requested a way to *simplify* its model, why do you propose a more complex model ? Also why the dissymmetry between Partner and Partner Witness ?