# Entity Relationship Diagram, generalization when only one class can interact with another class

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, software-design, erd

Let's imagine we have a User class, this is a generalization of two other classes: Admin and noAdmin 
There is a another class to which only an Admin can interact with, let's call it only_admin

My question is, to what class should only_admin be related to? User or Admin?

[image: ERD]

Comment: `to what class should only_admin be related to? User or Admin?`: the simpler the better, so *Admin*, else you have to add a constraint

Comment: thanks, can you please give more information about that constraint?

Comment: I was editing my remark, I will put an answer finaly

Comment: Is this a question about UML or ERD? It can't be both.

Comment: I put my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `User` is associated with `Something`, then, all specializations of `User` (i.e. `Admin` **and** `NoAdmin`) would be associated with `Something` as well.

Therefore, if `Something` makes only sense with `Admin`,  then make the association with `Admin` only and not with `User`.  The diagram would be crystal clear and self-explaining.

**Additional remarks**:

- If `NoAdmin` has nothing specific compared to `User`, you do not need to have an own class for it.
- If things get more tricky, and `User` would have many more specializations, most of them being associated with `Something`, except a few, or if you'd have `SomethingForAdminOnly` which would be a specialization of `SomethingForAllUsers` you could have a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62973692/3723423).

Answer (score 2):

For the UML point of view as your class diagram

> to what class should only_admin be related to? User or Admin?

The simpler and clearer the better, so *Admin*, else you have to add a constraint `oclIsKindOf(Admin)` or `oclIsTypeOf(Admin)` (see below)

Anyway if this is allowed only for instances of *Admin* and not for instances of possible classes inheriting *Admin* the constraint is required typically using `oclIsTypeOf(Admin)`  even the relation is attached to *Admin* rather than *User*.

From [Object Constraint Language / formal/2014-02-03](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4) page 153:

> **oclIsTypeOf(type : Classifier) : Boolean**
>
> Evaluates to true if self is of the type t but not a subtype of t.
>
> post: self.oclType() = type
>
> **oclIsKindOf(type : Classifier) : Boolean**
>
> Evaluates to true if the type of self conforms to t. That is, self is of type t or a subtype of t.
>
> post: self.oclType().conformsTo(type)