# UML class diagram association properties {subsets < Association end > } | {union} | {redefines}

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

I don't quite understand what {subset} stands for when it comes to the association between class diagrams in UML. I've found this PDF that talks about it on page 4: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.5537&rep=rep1&type=pdf.
Here is the diagram & text that you can also find on page 4:

[image]

I read this and I'm not 100% about what {subsets < class > } is about.
It says that "The slot representing d will be a subset of the slot representing b. Elements of type B can be inserted into slot b and elements of type D can be inserted into slots b and d."
So, is {subset} some kind of polymorphism ? I think that thorugh "slot" they mean like the argument of a method that is of type B. And because D subsets b that means that D is like the sub-class of b so it can be passed down as "b" in arguments because of Polymorphism.

So the question is :
What is {subsets < class > } exactly, is it representing a sub class ?

On top of that I have other questions:
What are {union}, {redefines < class > }, {nonunique} & {sequence}. What do does stand for ?

Some examples in code would make it easier to understand.

Comment: Not directly related: this other SO question provided a concrete example of whats subset, redefines and association specialisation can help to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973692/how-to-model-a-covariant-association-class-in-uml -in the answers and comments there are references to inspiring articles on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is : What is {subsets < class > } exactly, is it representing a sub class ?

It is not *{subsets < class >}* but *{subsets < property name >}*

In the given diagram *D* is the only visible class specializing *B*, and if they are no other classes specializing *B* then all the instances of *B* are instances of *D* and then *{subset b}* is equal to *b*.

But having at least :

[image]

all the instances of *B* are not necessary instances of *D* (including of classes specializing *D*), this is why *d* only concerns a subset of the instances of *B* concerned by *b*.

In your diagram and mine the *subsets* are not really useful, but there are for instance in case of redefinition e.g. *{subsets a, redefines a} {subsets b, redefines b}*

---

> What are {union}, {redefines < class > }, {nonunique} & {sequence}

referring to [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML) §9.5.4 page 113 and 114 :

- *union* means that the property is a derived union of its subsets.
- *nonunique*: means that there may be duplicates in a multi-valued property. This is the opposite of *unique* meaning there is no possible duplicates. For instance supposing *b* is *{nonunique}* then some instances of *B* can be present several times in *b*. If the property is implemented in C++ by a `std::set` it is *{unique}*.
- *sequence* means that the property represents an ordered bag, this is a shortcut of *{nonunique, ordered}*. This is the case of `std::vector` and `std::list` in C++.
- *{redefines < property-name > }* (not *{redefines < class >}*) means that the property redefines an inherited property identified by *< property-name >*. If in your diagram the *{subsets b}* is replaced by *{redefines b}* then the classes *C* only has the slot (e.g. attribute in C++ etc) *d*. This is not like having *b* private so not accessible from *C*, that really means *d* is a redefinition of *b*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but do you have any examples where {subsets property-name} could be used in code ?

Comment: @David you can have code directly inspired from my class diagram, class A has attribute *b* of type B, class B has attribute *a* of type A, class C inheriting A has attribute *d* of type D, and class D inheriting B has attribute *c* of type C.

Comment: yes, but what about {subset property-name}. What you wrote was just about property association but not property subsetting. What I don't understand is what exactly {subsets property-name} is, what's the role of writing {subsets a} right under the c property ?

Comment: On top of that, I have seen that we can also write {subsets association-end}. What exactly is meant with association-end. Is the association-end and property-name the same thing ?

Comment: Is {subsets property-name} directed towards the class or the property. Do you mean by any chance that {subsets b}, under d, in this case means that you can use polymorphism in some cases since the class D is specializing the class B and pass it as type B in methods where the argument type needed is B ?