# Associate a user with an abstract class implementation based on their role

Tags: inheritance, uml, associations, class-diagram, class-design

Let's suppose that we have a User class that is necessarily associated with a Role, which can be DogLover or CatLover.

We have another abstract class called Animal, which has two implementations, Dog and Cat.

The User has an attribute called pet that will be a Cat or a Dog, depending on the Role chosen.

How can I show this on the diagram?

[image]

I cannot relate the implementation of each Animal with the Role since the animal must be associated with the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this design `Role` and `Animal` are covariant, because the `Role` specialisation express love for corresponding `Animal` specialisations.  There is unfortunately no easy way to model this.

One way of designing this is to use `pet:Animal` and model it with an association. You have then two options:

- simply define a constraint for `User`, that would require the pet type and the role type match. To facilitate this design, I'd even consider making the role's specialisation a template class, i.e. `Lover<T:Animal>`
- or make the role association a derived association (its name should be preceded with `/` ).  The derivation would be based on the real type of the pet. SO if the pet changes,  the derivation could change as well.

A better way to design this would be to move the pet from the `User` to the `Role`.  The user has no animal,  but in his/her role of `DogLover` he/she could have `Dog` (or `CatLover` a `Cat`). You can then use association specialization to clearly show the covariance. Several techniques can be used for this purpose as shown in the [answers to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62973692/3723423), for example:

[image]

This being said, in the real life, `DogLover` and `CatLover` are not necessarily incompatible,  and one could even have a `Dog` for historical reasons while being a `CatLover`.  **[Separating the concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/)** of ownership and preference, would be an even better design.

Comment: In this diagram, the Role-Animal association is not abstract. For example, an instance of DogLover may have a link with a Dog, but also a link with a Cat through the Role-Animal association. I don't think this is OP's intention.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl interesting remark.  Setting the end name identical at both end should be an implicit redefinition and limit this (unless an explicit redefine is preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63122039/3723423 ?).